# Word counter of a vector without map

Tags: c++, vector, counter

How can I count the number of occurences of each word in a vector of words ?

I was able to get all the words in the vector but now I can't count how many times each word occured.

```
vector <Phrase> mots; // it's already filled with words of type Phrase (string)
int count = 1;
Phrase *word = &mots[0];
for (unsigned i = 1; i < mots.size(); i ++ ){
        if ( word != &mots[i] ){
             cout << *word <<" occured " << count << " times " <<endl;
             count = 0;
             word = &mots[i]; // I'm pretty sure I'm doing this line wrong 
        }
      count ++;
 }
cout << word <<" occured " << count << " times " <<endl;
```

Thanks

Here where I populate the vector:
these are iterators for the texts

```
for( Histoire * histoire : * histoires ) {
      for( Phrase p : * histoire ) {
            for ( Phrase w : p ){
                        mots.push_back(w);
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think using pointers is going to help?

Comment: Instead of a vector, use a `map<string, int>` to store the number of occurences of each word with the word itself.

Comment: You don't need to (and in fact, probably shouldn't be using) pointers for this solution. `vector` is able to be iterated either with range-based iteration or using `begin`/`end`.

Comment: how can i achieve this without a vector ?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Well the question title says "without map."

Comment: @cdhowie I know, but then any reasonable solution would probably involve making some sort of (slower, buggier) `map`-equivalent. The problem here requires associating a value (count) with a key (word), which maps are made for.

Comment: @KingAzaiez If you want to use a vector and you don't want to use a map, then one way to do this is to sort the vector. Then all the similar words end up adjacent to each other in the vector and so it's relatively easy to count how many times each word occurs.

Comment: *"how can i achieve this without a vector"* - What do you mean. Your question clearly states you *have* a vector of strings. `vector <Phrase> mots`. Now you asking how to get counts of words within that vector, but without the vector? Um.. Huh?

Comment: @KingAzaiez But looking at your code maybe the vector is sorted already but you didn't tell us that? That would certainly make a bit more sense of your code.

Comment: @WhozCraig He said better not use a vector, so I asked him what do I use beside map

Comment: @KingAzaiez Your C++ instructor is telling you _not_ to use `std::vector`? What does he suggest you use instead? Perhaps `std::list` since insertion is O(1)?

Comment: @cdhowie he's telling me not to use map as well :)

Comment: @KingAzaiez What he suggests you _not_ use is significantly less interesting than what he is _trying to get you to use instead_.

Comment: I'm actually going to put all the words after in an AVL tree so I figured that I use a vector, count the words frequency then put them in the tree

Comment: @KingAzaiez No, that's exactly the wrong approach. You put them in the tree specifically so you can keep track of their frequency while you are processing them; the vector step is unnecessary waste. The tree should use `std::string` as its key and an integral type like `int` as the value. When you see a word you insert it with value 1 if it's not present; otherwise you increment the counter on the already-existing node.

Comment: @cdhowie sir, you just made my day, so all this vector is unnecessary ? thanks alot brother. I'll work on it now

Comment: @KingAzaiez well seems like that my solution has worked ahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can emulate a `map<string, int>` with a `vector<pair<string, int>>`, and you will ends up with something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> mots = {"a", "b", "c", "a", "c"}; // <- this is just for the example
vector<pair<string, int>> counts;
std::for_each(mots.begin(), mots.end(), [&](auto& el){ // <- for each word
    auto index = std::find_if(counts.begin(), counts.end(), [&](auto & pair){
        return pair.first == el;
    }); // <- check if you already have registered in counts a pair with that string
    if(index == counts.end()) // <- if no, register with count 1
        counts.emplace_back(el, 1);
    else // otherwise increment the counter
        (*index).second++;
});
for(auto& el : counts)
    cout << "Word " << el.first << " occurs "<< el.second << " times";
```

Output:

```
Word a occurs 2 times
Word b occurs 1 times
Word c occurs 2 times
```